# Dynamically detect textarea empty or not

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically detect if a textarea is empty or not. I'm doing this so I can show a send button only when there's text entered in the textarea.

I tried this code below, but it's not working.

```
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

if (text !== ''){
    alert("works");
    document.getElementById("sendicon1").style.display = "none";         
    document.getElementById("sendicon2").style.display = "inline";         
}
else{
    alert("not working");
    document.getElementById("sendicon2").style.display = "none";         
    document.getElementById("sendicon1").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: What exactly "isn't working"?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`onchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)? I can't offer a more specific solution without a better idea of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy with `input` event.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("text");
textarea.addEventListener('input', hideOnEmpty);
function hideOnEmpty() {
    var text = this.value;
    if (text !== ''){
        alert("works");
        document.getElementById("sendicon1").style.display = "none";         
        document.getElementById("sendicon2").style.display = "inline";         
    }
    else{
        alert("not working");
        document.getElementById("sendicon2").style.display = "none";         
        document.getElementById("sendicon1").style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

See input event documentation for further details ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput), [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)). This code will fire `hideOnEmpty` function every time that content of textarea is changed.

Beware - this code will not work in IE8 or lower, and can fail to detect deletions in IE9 (but there is no reliable way to check if input has changed without polling in IE9).

Answer (score 3):

Are you putting that code inside an onkeyup or onchange function? You could do something like:

```
window.onload = function() { 
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var func = function() { 
    if (text.value !== '') {
      alert("works");
      document.getElementById("sendicon1").style.display = "none";         
      document.getElementById("sendicon2").style.display = "inline";         
    } else {
      alert("not working");
      document.getElementById("sendicon2").style.display = "none";         
      document.getElementById("sendicon1").style.display = "inline";       
    }
  }
  text.onkeyup = func;
  text.onchange = func;
}
```

You don't need both the onkeyup and onchange, it depends on when you are looking for it to fire. onchange will be after you have taken focus away (blur) and onkeyup will be after each key is pressed inside the textarea.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't listed jQuery as a dependency, but this is definitely an area where it would come it handy.

```
$('#text').on('input propertychange', function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
       $("#sendicon1").hide();
       $("#sendicon2").show();
    }
    else {
       $("#sendicon2").hide();
       $("#sendicon1").show();    
    }
});
```

The `input` event will detect all changes to the textarea- key presses, copying and pasting, and more.

Comment: Appreciate feedback on the -1.

Comment: you're right but the event you listen for should be 'keyup' or 'change' depending on when you want it to change (if you lose focus -> change, instant -> keyup)

Comment: @VDP That's not true. `input` is an event that fires on all change to an input - which is absolutely applicable in OP's use case.

Comment: OP did not ask for jQuery solution.

Comment: @Ginden SO answers often recommend libraries for easy functionality - how is this any different? I acknowledge in my answer that it would require installing jQuery but it's ubiquitous enough that I think it's valuable to have this answer, if not for OP, then for someone else with a similar problem.